# Sketch the vector equation:$ r(t) = (2\cos(t), 2\sin(t), 1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, graphing-functions

Given the parametric equations:
$$x = 2\cos(t), \quad y=2\sin(t), \quad z = 1.$$

We know that $x^2 + y^2 = 4\cos^2(t) + 4\sin^2(t) = 4(\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t)) = 4$.

In other problems, I've seen this fact tell us that the graph lies on the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$. However, in this case, $z$ is a constant. Does this mean that the 3D graph looks like a circle with radius of $2$, at $z = 1$?

Comment: A circle of radius $\;2\;$  arround $\;(0,0,1)\;$ and contained in the plane $\;z=1\;$ . If you meant this then yes: you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, circle at z = 1

Answer (score 1):

You are right and this is the circle.

[image]

Comment: Nice image. I struggle at getting graphs and images online. Can you direct me to software and instructions that will help?

Comment: It is : https://www.geogebra.org/ ( with  examples and instructions on line)

Comment: Thanks. Must get organized to use it.